# How to add perl-mode.el to .emacs?

Tags: linux, perl, emacs, elisp

If I do `M-x load-file RET /root/.elisp/perl-mode.el RET` then this [perl-mode.el](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/annotate/head:/lisp/progmodes/perl-mode.el) get loaded correctly.

If I in `.emacs` add any of these, it doesn't work

```
(load "/root/.elisp/perl-mode.el")
(load-file "/root/.elisp/perl-mode.el")
```

I am using emacs 24.1.1.

The error I get is

```
File mode specification error: (void-function setq-local)
```

**Question**

What is the correct way to load `perl-mode.el` from `.emacs`?

Comment: All three should be equivalent.  How do you notice that it doesn't work?  Does it work if you put _only_ one of those lines in `.emacs`?

Comment: `/root/`?!  Are you sure that you have the necessary permissions to access this file?

Comment: If that directory is in your load path, you could also try `(require 'perl-mode)`.

Comment: @Dan Then I get the same error. Just updated OP with error msg.

Comment: @lunaryorn Yes, I run as root, so permissions should be fine.

Comment: @legoscia I have updated the OP with the error msg I get. Same error even just just one of the lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro `setq-local` was introduced in Emacs 24.3, so this version of `perl-mode` is too new for the Emacs you're currently running (24.1).

You could upgrade Emacs, or you could just put the definition of `setq-local` into your `.emacs` (from [here](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/annotate/head:/lisp/subr.el)):

```lisp
(defmacro setq-local (var val)
  "Set variable VAR to value VAL in current buffer."
  ;; Can't use backquote here, it's too early in the bootstrap.
  (list 'set (list 'make-local-variable (list 'quote var)) val))
```